# I am migrating my angular application from Angular 8 to Angular 9, while i am trying to install @angular/cli@9 i am getting peer dependencies error

Tags: html, css, angular, migration

while migrating angular 8 to angular 9, i am getting below error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CUa1.jpg)

I am getting error with message stating that "Migration Failed : Incompatible peer dependencies found"

Guide me out here how can I resolve this

I tried with the command ng update @angular/cli@9 for installing the dependencies for migration angular/cli from version 8 to version 9, i am getting these errors when it got fails.

My expectation is to install all packages on @angular/cli@9 without errors.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.